# Multi-booting Debian 11 and Ubuntu 22-04, GRUB creates shim error

Tags: debian, ubuntu, grub2

I am trying to run Debian 11, Ubuntu 22.04, and Windows 10 pro via multi-boot.

Windows boots normally.

However, the latter installed Linux boots normally, while the former gives the following errors after choosing it from GRUB's menu:

```
error: bad shim signature
error: you need to load the kernel first
press any key to continue ...
```

So, if I install Debian first, I can choose Ubuntu from Grub menu, but Debian will give the above errors. If I install Ubuntu first, it is the other way around.

In all cases, I boot everything normally from the BIOS menu (UEFI).

If I disable secure boot from BIOS, GRUB works fine, but I don't think this is a good solution.

HP Z2 mini G5

Comment: Why is disabling secure boot not a good solution? I don't know if it is even possible to have multiple Linux distros with multiple shims booting with secure boot enabled on the same machine. It might be, but even if it is, it is bound to be really quite complicated for very little actual security benefit.

Comment: @terdon it was added as an extra layer of security, however, there is debate around the pros / cons, *e.g.; https://askubuntu.com/questions/843656/is-it-safe-to-disable-secure-boot). I would rather keep it turned on until I am forced to disable it.